# How can i make this error dissapear from the VueJs 2 template?

Tags: javascript, templates, vuejs2

When I create a new template I keep having this error. It only works if I put all that div in a single line.

[image: Example error]

Answer (score 1):

The way to create multiline html code is to use `\` backslash at the end of each line. Backslash tells JavaScript engine that the string will continue to the next line

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div class="tabs">\
    <ul>\
        <li>One</li>\
      <li>Two</li>\
  </div>'
})
```

Example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jy4t06aj/1/)

Better way: **Single File Components**

Your approach is nice for small templates, but how complexity of project growth it will become ugly with all slashes for multiline HTML.
After you learn template syntax, also check [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)